# How do I connect to Cassandra with the C++ driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-c++-driver

I am trying to connect cassandra with c++ in linux ‘titan’ by using the cmake .nothing in the internet useful I found,

Can anyone help me with steps please?

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are packages available for RHEL/CentOS and Ubuntu on the [C++ driver Installation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest/topics/) page. You can find the download links for the dependencies on the same page.

You'll need to install the dependencies and runtime library. See the [Installation instructions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest/topics/installation/) for details.

Once you've installed the driver, try running the sample code for connecting to a Cassandra cluster in the [C++ driver Getting started guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest/topics/). Cheers!